# Oracle block level locking for bitmap indexes in an OLTP environment where using static tables

Tags: oracle, locking, database-indexes

I would like to use the power of bitmap indexes for tables where the indexed column has lots of repeating values, however I am in an OLTP environment. The rule is that you must not use bitmap indexes in an OLTP environment, since it causes block level locking when rows in the table are updated. I definitely do not want block level locking.

My table is however very static, that is it is very unlikely that a row will be added to it. Also two people would not add rows at the same time, so locking for that table is not that important.

My concern however is whether the locking on the table with the bitmap indexes could cause locking on other tables if the table is used in DML, DDL or sql statements along with other tables.

So is it safe to use a bitmap index in this scenario and can it cause locking in tables other than the table with the bitmap index.

For example:

Table `per_person_types`:

```
person_type_id description internal_name
1              Contractor  EMP
2              Employee    EMP
3              Terminated  TERM
```

where I want the bitmap index on `internal_name`.

Comment: It depends what "OLTP environment". Even in a OLTP environment you may have tables which never change their data (maybe apart if you run an upgrade). Also a "Datawarehouse environment" may consist tables with permanent DML's on it. So, check your application. If a certain table is static then bitmap indexes should work fine.

Comment: The OLTP environment is Oracle Applications HR and Payroll. There are no data warehouse or Business Intelligence tables.

Comment: Why do you want to use bitmap indexes vs btree?

Comment: Because bitmap indexes are the correct index type to use when there are lots of repeating values as opposed to distinct values (for which you would use a btree index).

Comment: What? No they aren't. They combine well if you have multiple low-cardinality columns that you use in combination. For just one column on what looks like a small table I doubt you would see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to use a bitmap index here.

The rule is *per table*, not *per environment*.  It doesn't matter how volatile the database is, as long as the relevant table is static then bitmap indexes won't cause locking issues.

From [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT88846), part of the conditions for using a bitmap index are:

> The indexed table is either read-only or not subject to significant
>   modification by DML statements.

Oracle stores lock information with the data.  It does not track all locks in a global table.  Locking unrelated objects will generally not cause too many locks, lock escalation, or other problems.

Also, bitmap indexes don't specifically lock per-block.  The bitmaps can be compressed, and updating a single row can potentially lock the entire table.

If you're still nervous about bitmap indexes you could try using btree index compression instead.  For highly repetitive values it can significantly shrink the size of the index, making it faster for some operations.